# Filter out a list from list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I am trying to compare elements of a list with elements of list of lists.

I have a list and a list of lists with different combination of same courses (each list is a different topological sort)

The `list_of_lists` in some cases is huge. 
What I want to do is to compare the `courses_taken` list with the `list_of_lists` and take as a result the non-common elements of each list, for example:

```
# the small list:
courses_taken = ['CS350','CS450']

# a list of lists:
list_of_lists =[['CS450', 'CS350', 'CS300', 'CS206', 'CS306'], ['CS450', 'CS350', 'CS206', 'CS306', 'CS300'], ['CS450', 'CS350', 'CS206', 'CS300', 'CS306'],...]

# the result:
result = [['CS300', 'CS206', 'CS306'], ['CS206', 'CS306', 'CS300'], [ 'CS206', 'CS300', 'CS306']]
```

From the research I did I found only ways to compare the courses_taken with a sublist and not each specific elements in order to return the non-common ones. Also, I found ways to compare 2 lists but the same code would not work for this case.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This seems like a common problem. Did you try searching this to see if there was already a solution you could use?

Comment: @Todd actually I'm sure we could find an answer to it but I have searched, In this case it is just easier to supply an answer (as you did) and it will be closed later on by other contributor.

Comment: @Todd To be honest I could not find an answer even though I searched. I only found way to print the common ones or to compare the whole list as a list with each sublist and not the elements. Maybe there is something I didn't find. If that's the case then my mistake. All in all, thank you both for your help!

Comment: you're welcome. and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really easy list comprehension would be:

```
>>> result = [[x for x in group if x not in courses_taken] for group in list_of_lists]
>>> # output: [['CS300', 'CS206', 'CS306'], ['CS206', 'CS306', 'CS300'], ['CS206', 'CS300', 'CS306']]
```

Comment: this actually worked perfectly in just one line without the need of creating a set of the list. Thank you so much!

Comment: The reason for making a set from the list, @piggy is because the `in` operation on lists is tremendously SLOW. The difference in using `in` with a list versus a set in loops can be very noticeable. It can turn an operation that takes a minute into one that takes a few seconds. I mentioned that if the list were longer, then it would matter in my answer. You can select which answer you prefer, but technically, mine gives better advice.

Comment: My mistake then, I did not know that and probably I did not give attention to it when you wrote it at your answer. Since that's the case, your answer might help me more in long term, given the fact that the list will become a lot bigger at some point. Thank you once more @Todd !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `set` with the `courses_taken` for faster `in` operations - it would matter if courses taken were a long list.

Then just iterate over your list of lists and build a new list that checks for set inclusion.

```
>>> ctset = set(courses_taken)
>>> result = [[item for item in li if item not in ctset] for li in list_of_lists]
>>>
>>> # Or if it really matters, it can be a one-liner.
>>> result = [[item for item in li if item not in set(courses_taken)] for li in list_of_lists]
```

To demonstrate the difference between checking a `list` for group membership versus a `set`, we can set up a couple timeit tests.

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> li = list(range(5000))
>>> se = set(li)
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit("randint(0, 5000) in li", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
33.735417196992785
>>> timeit.timeit("randint(0, 5000) in se", globals=globals(), number=10**6)
1.196909729973413
>>>
```

In this case, the set operations were over 30x faster.

This demonstrates a case where the time-complexity of operations on two different data types comes into play. Checking a `set` for group membership is an O(1) operation, where it's an O(n) operation for lists.

The number of operations in this test is pretty high, but it can be comparable to certain applications. I have a solution to a combinatorics problem that involves a lot of group membership checking that was very slow until I changed my lists to sets. So this does translate into real-world application performance.

If you are curious about operations on other data types, you can check out this reference: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: it works great, but in the answer of Missilexent it worked in just one line of code and for that reason I chose that one. But this one works as well!

Comment: I hope you understand that your criteria wasn't all that sound ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation on the topic!